# How to make the light emission invisible?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I was experimenting with a scene with an object that is unwrapped so that every polygon has the same texture so that I can use it as a wireframe. The object is sitting on a plane. I tried this node setup, but it is not as I expected, because for some reason the main material casts light.[image: example 1]

[image: node setup]
Here is what I want to achieve: the wireframe should be a light source that doesn't cast light. By the way, there is no other light source in the scene that is lighting the object.

However, it works this way:
[image]

[image: node setup 2]

However, in this way only the wireframe of the object is visible.
How can I make the wireframe only to be a light source and not to cast any light?

If I confused anybody, then this is what I mean:
http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/10/20/blender-tip-creating-invisible-lights-in-cycles/

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8108/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *Light path* node to mix shaders based on the properties of the incoming ray.

For example, this node setup mixes *Base material* and *Line material* based on *Line texture*, then mixes that with *Base material* based on the kind of incoming ray; rays coming directly from the camera will see the mix of *Base* and *Line*, but other rays will "see" only *Base*.

[image]

So shadows and indirect lighting etc. will be cast as if *Base shader* was connected straight to the material output.

[image]