# Lighting problem in cyles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, light

I have a problem with lighting that i can't fix, I have a mesh in the form of a light bulb with an emission material set to the strength of 5000 and no matter what i up the strength to the bulb object has practically no effect on my scene, I will also mention that there is some glossy material in the scene aswell, Sorry if this question is noobish but i am still learning the arm of blender any help would be greatly appreciated [image: My scene with an emission light bulb no effect on the scene]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cycles doesn't really like very small light sources with very high lighting intensity.

They are very 'hard to find' computationally speaking. Cycles is a [Path Tracer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing) and will cast rays from the camera until the reach a light source, if the light source is too small it is very hard to hit, statistically speaking, creating very noisy renders that take a very long time to render.

Large light sources with an average lighting intensity are much better suited.

Keep you detailed lamp model if you like, but don't make it the light source of your scene.

Add a fake light material to it then use a real lamp object or a simpler geometry like an emission plane to actually light your scene up. Also avoid transparent or blocking geometry over your light sources, like the glass bulb.

You can then make fake light in cycles [How to make the light emission invisible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-to-make-the-light-emission-invisible) or [How to make a cycles light emisson object invisible to the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera)

Comment: Thanks so much man!, I've managed to fix my problem thanks to your solution :), Your answer is much appreciated

Comment: If the answer was useful please consider marking it as correct if it solved your problem, or at least up-voting if it helped. It will help other people find it in the future

Comment: How do I mark the question as solved, Sorry if this question is noobish? Thanks in advance

Comment: By the left side of the question there should be two big round buttons, one for upvoting and one for downvoting. Bellow that there should be a check-mark to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I have marked it as solved thanks a lot man :)

Comment: Most welcome, happy Blending

Answer (score 0):

You must dispense better the illumination and lower these giant "5000.000 values?. Add any image is much hdri sky environment first. Only that light will have a render burned "totally white if you leave render much time"

Comment: Not accurate. White doesn't exist in the scene.