# Closed interior lighting renders too dark with cycles

Tags: lighting

I'm working with a closed scene without any window with some lights, my render tend to be dark and more noisy. When I have very strong of lights, it will make some area become over-bright while other area still too dark. I think its far away from the reality where I have the same big of room with 5w of led lamp. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

It's a 3x3x3m of white room, the area above the lamp will be over-bright where the bottom left of the camera will be darker blackened. It doesn't matter if I change the light bounces to 200 or more, or if i change the world surface strength up. Everything just the same, except the renders quality.

Comment: Hello, it really depends on your setup, could you add screenshots of your scene ?

Comment: Thank you for responding, I've edited my question.
I'm using blender default settings.

Comment: Scenes are generally illuminated with lamp objects, emission shaders are often inefficient. A single screenshot is not enough to diagnose the issue. Could you show the rendered result, your render settings, exposure, compositing, gamma etc? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65243/emission-material-wont-work-while-another-emission-in-my-scene-is-on/

Comment: Thank you, it explains why. Make fake lights does help the exposure, but it'll create false shadow.
The sun light and world light does not work inside a closed box without any hole.
I'm looking for a more simpler ways to configure the lights. What I'm trying to do is to reduce the light strength near the lamp and increase the the light strength in the area far from the lamp plus making the whole scene more brighter, without editing the rendered images.

Comment: Rightnow, the best thing I can do is using ies texture for the lamp. But It'll make the floor over-bright with not enough light to the ceiling.