# How to fill a mesh with solid color

Tags: mesh, texture-painting

Given a 3D model, I want to define different regions and fill each region with solid color (to distinguish)

Is there an easy way to do it?

My current solution is to first select faces under edit mode, then switch to vertex paint mode and paint use a brush. I changed some properties of the brush(large radius, reduce edge softness) but I can't make regions in solid color as I expected..

Please Help.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create multiple materials for the object in the *materials* tab of the *properties* panel.  Then, on edit mode, use the *assign* buttons in the *materials* tab to give the selected faces the selected material.  By default all faces are assigned the first material you create.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** the rendering properties of a material can be found in the *surface* rollout.  But materials, by default, have a gray viewport color, this can be changed for each material at the bottom of the material's settings.

Answer (score 0):

For continuous gradient elaborate color such as the colors of a flower then consider texture mapping.  You can paint or paste on the flat map or paint a texture in 3D.
Videos exist for these techniques.  UV Unwrap and then texture paint.

If you want say solid stripes on a cylinder PG has already given a good answer.

Vertex Color must have the context set correctly to work.  I suspect people rarely use it.  There are videos for that topic as well.

Comment: I like this idea too. I choose set vertex color under vertex paint mode, and the result can be exported to ply format easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Once you know, its super easy...

I came across this feature by just playing and testing things with Blender.

First you go in to the `material`s tab, as shown below.

[image]

Now you will see this. Press new to create a "`material`":

[image]

The next screen that comes up should look like this:

[image]

Click "Base Color" (if you don't know where that is my mouse is hovering over it)

Now this menu will pop-up:

[image]

Use the color picker or RGB/Hex/HSV values to choose.

**NOTE:**
If you want to see the texture before the rendering, change the mode to material mode like this:

[image]

Works fine tested on 2.93.2!

Hope I help :D