# How can I give a single object multiple colors in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm making a sun and I would like it to be a mix of colors - such that every face has a different color, like on a ColorRamp. So, I want the final thing instead of just being a flat orange color to also have some reds and yellows merging in with the orange so it's an array of different colors. How can I do this in Cycles, by using the node editor?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload some kind of mockup or reference image showing what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can assign a [different material to each face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16398) on your model, I don't think that will give the result you want. I expect you want to use some noise to get colour variations, one way is to feed the noise into a colour ramp node.

[image]

[image]

There are other noise textures such as wave, voronoi, musgrave or magic that can give varying results, you may even want to mix a couple together. Just experiment with the scale, distortion and detail values to get a variation that you like.

Comment: It needs some kind of mapping coordinates in order for this to work.

Comment: By default you get generated texture coordinates, if that doesn't give the desired result you can add a texture coordinates node to choose other coordinates and add a mapping node for adjustment if you want more control.

Comment: This one works great for me. I experimented with magic and wave to get what I wanted. Thanks @sambler