# Color Mesh Multiple Colors

Tags: python

I've seen [How to fill a mesh with solid color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/how-to-fill-a-mesh-with-solid-color/16398#16398), and it is not quite what I would like to do.

Essentially, I am programatically building a mesh in python, then showing the user. I'd like to be able to set each face a different color.
For example, I'd like to do Domain colouring like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring , but in 3D. Is there any way that I can do this?

Help is much appreciated