# export to .3ds with smoothing groups?

Tags: export

Does anybody know if you can export to .3ds with smoothing groups in your model? I am trying to export to .3ds because of the fact that Battlefield 1942 has a tool called 3ds convertor (yes, it's name is spelled like that) that converts .3ds to .sm which stands for standard mesh, and is the native 3D format for Battlefield 1942. Also, Battlefield 1942 standard mesh models uses the material ID feature in 3ds Max for this to define different materials for what kind of surface the model should have.

Comment: Blender doesn't have a concept of Smoothing groups like 3ds max, here you define sharp edges, but they should be kept intact when exported to 3ds. Material IDs are called material slots, and should also be exported faithfully by default

Comment: I see. Well, can you tell me how you define the slots in numbers, so that I can define a surface for my collision mesh?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/how-to-fill-a-mesh-with-solid-color/16398#16398. You can't specifically define slot numbers, just slot order

Comment: Alright, I will see if that can solve the issue. Otherwise I'll have to go through Gmax to get it done. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: I posted in the bug section of Blender, and it seems that the smoothing group export feature probably won't be added.

Comment: Bug reports are not for feature requests

Comment: Yes, I found that out. I won't make that mistake again though.