# Cycles Green screen?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

How would I make a green screen that has absolutely 0% reflection, and does not cast or receive shadows? I tried making a plane and making a material and changing the background color, but every time there would be a reflection on the objects in the scene.

Comment: Why do you need the greenscreen? Can't you just render the background as transparent? Also try compositing

Answer (score 7):

This is what the *Holdout shader* is for:

[image]

This shader affects the alpha channel when *Transparent* is enabled in *Render settings > film*.

If you *really* want to create an actual "greenscreen", then see [Node for setting render colour, regardless of lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8108/599)