# A project without lighting?

Tags: rendering, materials, light

How can I render a scene in blender without any lighting? by that I mean I want to have textures, and if the texture is say #00FF00 green, then I want that to render exactly as #00FF00. No light or shadow or any such alteration of the texture color.

Is this possible?

(please excuse my use of hex codes to represent a color. I'm sure blender used something more involved to process colors)

Thanks.

Comment: you can change the emission to the colour you want

Answer (score 5):

If using Cycles Render, In Properties Panel, go to Render Layers tab, under Passes, under Diffuse, check Color, then render your scene, When render is done, in Compositor, link the Diffuse Color in the Render results node to the Output node, you'll get the diffuse only.
[image]

**Edit:** My apologies for the mistake, I mentioned earlier that you should check Diffuse Direct, I corrected the answer since Diffuse Color should be checked.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Blender Internal, you can check the "Shadeless" option in the material tab. If you're using Cycles, then check out this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting).