# Making a shadeless card

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do you make a shadeless billboard/card sort of material (with working alpha) in Blender Cycles? I just need to make the image/movie file show up shadelessly on a flat plane, specifically with an effect from the alpha channel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node for setting render colour, regardless of lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting)

Comment: What kind of problems with the setup exposed in the related question do you face while dealing with alpha?

Comment: I simply am unable to make the alpha channel affect the transparency of the final material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Emission Shader + Alpha masking

Shadeless material in cycles can be obtained by using the Emission shader. For further instruction on how to handle all the interactions with other objects in the scene and dealing with shadow casting, I'll suggest to read: 
[Read Node for setting render colour, regardless of lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting)

The alpha of the image can be used to control the shading property of the object by using as an input of a *Mix Shader* that mix the Emission shader and a trasparent shader.

Here's a possible node setup.

[image]