# Connecting alpha node when adding material causes a weird spazzy cloud

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

So I ripped this model from a game, but it came in several pieces so I'm just adding it together. When I added this hair texture the back of his bangs wouldn't get textured unless I also connected the alpha node, but when I do this weird cloud appears and if i move the camera it spazzes out. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: The "weird cloud" is a rendered volume, because you connected the Alpha to the Volume Material Output input socket. That is definitely not where you want Alpha to go. But you should be able to render the image without connecting Alpha at all; Alpha should only be needed if you require transparency.

Comment: Ah I see, but when I don't connect the alpha the back of the bangs doesn't get textured so they have this ugly black outline. If I put the alpha into the displacement socket it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file? The volume cloud was a red herring, and it is hard to debug the primary issue without seeing it. It would probably also make sense to ask a separate question about the primary issue (that the bangs aren't getting textured/rendering as expected).

Comment: I'd suggest watching tutorials about Blender's node editor. You really shouldn't plug the texture directly into the material output. If you want a shadeless material: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting The yellow socket for color should be connected to another socket that expects a color input, such as the color sockets of the shader nodes (e.g. Principled BSDF, Emission BSDF, ...)

Comment: I'll create a new question thread then.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Oh I didn't know that was a problem, I saw a tutorial that advised just doing this. I really haven't used blender before and I mostly just wanna play around with posing this model once its all together and rigged.

Comment: Adding back the default node that comes up for new object and connecting through that fixed it, thanks for your help guys.