# How to make an object not receive light from world?

Tags: materials, node-editor, light, world, reflection

I have a project of a character laying on a plane and the world is full of stars. Problem is the colors of the world are reflecting on the character whereas i want him to be free from all reflections. Is there any way for the stars to be only reflected in the plane and not on the character?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you can only do it through the Compositor

Comment: can you explain how? or refer me to a proper guide of achieving this? many thanks.

Comment: actually if you're using the world to create your background I'm also curious to know how you can achieve it, I hope someone will tell

Comment: i found the solution to my problem here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting