# How to render objects only with their materials diffuse color or without lighting

Tags: python, rendering, materials, light, render-layers

I am currently trying to write a python script with bpy and Blender 2.9 to render images of a couple of thousand wavefront objects with material information. I only need the "true colors" of the objects, without shading, so I first tried to disable all light sources in the scene, what I could not accomplish because I am completely new to blender.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? Is there a way to set a uniform light source like the Hemi Lamp in previous blender versions? Is there a way to pass only the diffuse color of the materials?
I am quite stuck at the moment and would really appreciate any advice and bpy code examples.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an Emission shader. This will emit the intensity of the surface without responding to any surrounding light sources so will produce a pure "unshaded" colour.

Related: [Node for setting render colour, regardless of lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting)