# Can I import images as planes without them being affected by the lighting in the scene?

Tags: lighting

I am working on a 2d short film and planning to do the FX and compositing on Blender. My problem is that when I import an image as a plane, the image becomes reliant on the lighting in the scene. Is there a way to have an image in the 3d scene that doesn't rely on the lighting in the scene? As in, can I import an image in Blender, delete the light from the scene, and have the image look exactly like I had it in photoshop? (see images below to visualise). I hope this makes sense.

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I'll have a chat with the others to see what the consensus is .. I'm not sure that this _is_ actually a duplicate if you take more of the specific details into account? It's a toss-up .. see my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/303530/35559), on the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Shader Editor*, plug the *Image Texture* node into a *Shader > Emission* that you plug into the *Output*:

[image]

Comment: You can simply plug the texture in the _Material Output_, no need for an _Emission_ shader.

Comment: Yes I know, since the latest versions

Comment: Yeah, well since 2.80 now which is more than 4 years old if you count that as "latest versions"  ;)

Comment: Sure but it's always better to know the basic nodes, plugging directly into the Output is like plugging an Emission

Comment: I guess I'm a bit sensitive here :D It's maybe just because I'm always annoyed from that one youtuber who (despite using _Node Wrangler_) always plugs any node output into the _Emission Color_ of a _Principled BSDF_ only for previewing purposes instead of Ctrl+Shift+LMB which is so quick and handy... he doesn't want to create a shadeless material what is asked for here, it's just a quick preview. That bothers me each time. Sorry to project that huff onto your answer :)

Comment: plugin into the Emission of the Principled BSDF doesn't even give the same as Ctrl Shift LMB or as a simple Emission, it's still a mix between Diffuse (with Specularity) and Emission

Comment: hi @moonboots and Gordon Brinkmann, thanks so much for your answers. If I could just ask one more thing: I have a fake caustics effect on that 2d BG (see the vertical lighter lines on the second image) and the moment I plug the Image Texture into the Material Output, I get the desired effect of the light not affecting the BG but the fake caustics effect disappears along with it. Is there a way to retain it? thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hello could you please pack your images (File >External Data > Pack Resources), save and share your file?

Comment: Hello @moonboots, I just uploaded the file here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jL67kszX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jL67kszX/) thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using 2 planes, they are overlapping which creates a problem of Z-fighting, the image disappears, why don't you use one plane only?

Comment: hey @moonboots, I am very new to Blender which means everything I do with the software is clumsy at the moment. The reason I split it in two planes was to have the one caustics effect that goes on the side of the pool and a different shaped caustic effect going on the bottom of the pool to give the impression of two different planes. I don't know how to do that in one plane...

Comment: So shouldn't the plane be perpendicular rather than overlapping?