# How is IsShadowRay used in IAP_SHADELESS?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes

I am trying to understand the IAP_SHADELESS node group created by the Import Images as Planes addon for shadeless materials. It looks like this

[image]

([Light Path Node docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html), [Ray Type docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html#ray-types))

This switches between an emission and diffuse shader based on the light path, similar to the popular shadeless node setup in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8110/88681), but more complicated.

If you think for a while, you'll realize this uses emission exactly when

```
(RayDepth <= 1 and IsGlossyRay) or   # Camera Ray to Glossy?
IsShadowRay or                       # Shadow?
RayDepth == TransmissionDepth        # Camera or Refracted?
```

The third condition, `RayDepth == TransmissionDepth` is similar to using `IsCameraRay`, but works when the image is viewed through layers of glass.

[image]

The first condition, `RayDepth <= 1 and IsGlossyRay`, works when the image is seen in a mirror (but only one bounce?).

[image]

**What is the second condition, `IsShadowRay`, for?** Answers with a picture preferred.