# How to Render an image of a mesh with texture with Blender4.0, so texture is shadeless

Tags: rendering, image, shadeless

I just want to render an image of my model , which have a texture, It comes from photogrammetry and I need to export an ortophoto, which shouldn't have any shadows.
In previous versions, I only had to click Shadeless in material tab. (Now still can do it when importing an image.)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have different older versions of Blender here. Could you please tell us where you can click "Shadeless" in the material tab? Maybe show a screenshot? In which version you could do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8108/88681

Comment: "In previous versions" - this was a setting in the Blender internal render engine, this does not exist anymore since the introduction of _Eevee_ in version 2.80

Comment: so he is right "previous versions" 

Comment: The duplicate question is a poor answer to the question in my opinion. I feel they are looking for [Material Overrides](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/layers/introduction.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy-types-viewlayer-material-override) with an emissive material.

Comment: @Chris In a way... :D But mentioning having this problem with 4.0 and not having it in previous versions sounded a lot like, "I'm always using the latest version but since the latest release, something is missing". It took me a while to remember this option existed in Blender internal render engine...

Comment: @AlpineWorldCup I don't think so. It is mentioned nowhere that there are several materials to be overridden with a single material (it is a photogrammetry model with a textured material that should be shadeless), and the linked duplicate explains how to make it shadeless with an emissive material.

Comment: @PilukaPV could you clarify if the linked duplicate solves your issue? If not could you describe which part is missing or what part doesn't satisfy your needs?

Comment: No, It didn't. But never mind, keep the question closed. My workmate found the solution to the issue.